# Cómo encontrar un Stored Procedure en SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedure, select2

Estimados buen día, seré mas especifica en las preguntas. He visto que los DBA's usan ciertos atajos para encontrar una tabla mediante codigo como también un stored procedure. En este caso tengo el nombre del **stored procedure** y uso el filtro para encontrarlo pero no aparece y otro DBA si, les agradeceré bastante la ayuda.

Comment: Realmente nos falta información acá, no sabemos cómo funciona tu stored procedure ni qué está haciendo el otro DBA.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que el si usa el mismo fltro. Lo importante aca no es que haga el stored procedure sino como lo encuentro. Hay una lista como de mas de 300 y hasta buscarlos se me pasa la hora.

Comment: No entiendo, si tienes el nombre del stored procedure, qué es lo que necesitas encontrar?

Comment: El código transac del Procedimiento.

Comment: Entonces puedes usar el procedimiento `sp_helptext`: `sp_helptext 'dbo.TuStoredProcedure'` o también usar la vista de sistema `sys.sql_modules`: `SELECT definition
FROM sys.sql_modules
WHERE OBJECT_NAME(object_id) = 'TuStoredProcedure'
`

Comment: Mil gracias! me ha servido.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

¿Estás buscando el SP por el explorador de objetos? podría ser que crearon el SP después de que tu conectaste el explorador y por eso no te aparece. En ese caso: has clic derecho en la carpeta *Programmability* de la Base de Datos donde debería estar, y luego en *Refresh* para actualizar la vista.

Si quieres buscarlo por código (e.g. para ver como funciona) hay varias vías, como este `SELECT`, que te devolverá el contenido del SP y algunas propiedades:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.sql_modules
WHERE OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) = 'sp_NombreDelProcedimientoAlmacenado'
```

Comment: se debe tener en cuenta el schema...

Answer (score 2):

Si solo deseas saber si existe el SP (y no su definición), no hace falta buscar en `sys.sql_modules`. Puedes buscar en `sys.objects` que además te muestra la fecha de creación y la fecha de la última modificación:

```
SELECT object_id as ID
    , name as Nombre
    , create_date as FechaCreacion
    , modify_date as FechaModificacion
FROM sys.objects
WHERE type = 'P' --Tipo procedimiento
    AND name = 'NombreProcedimientoABuscar'
```

Lo bueno de acostumbrarse a manejar `sys.objects` es que también puedes usarlo para consultar todo tipo de objetos en la base de datos, solo basta cambiar el filtro de `type`:

- `type = 'U'` - Para buscar tablas.
- `type = 'V'` - Para buscar vistas.
- `type = 'FN'` - Para buscar Funciones escalares.
- `type = 'TF'` - Para buscar Funciones de tabla.

Etc. Puedes ver los tipos de datos usando el siguiente *query*:

```
SELECT type, type_desc
FROM sys.objects
GROUP BY type, type_desc
ORDER BY type_desc
```

Incluso te puede servir si no sabes el nombre exacto de una tabla o procedimiento, solo usas el filtro de `name` con un `LIKE`:

```
SELECT object_id as ID
    , name as Nombre
    , create_date as FechaCreacion
    , modify_date as FechaModificacion
FROM sys.objects
WHERE name LIKE '%usuario%'
```

Espero te sirva para buscar más fácil objetos en la base de datos.

Answer (score 1):

Si usas Microsoft Sql Server Management Studio, debes seguir los siguientes pasos.

```
 1. Servidor  
 2. Databases  
 3. (Seleccionas tu base de datos) 
 4. Programmability Stored
 5. Procedures 
 6. (Buscas tu SP)
```

Answer (score 0):

me imagino que estas utilizando para trabajar el sql server management studio o alguna especie de ide o portal para la administración, de ser el caso en el que utilices sql server, está página debería poder orientarte un poco, https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms174178.aspx yo utilizo una función con la cual selecciono el nombre del stored procedure y pesiono ctrl+(0-9) y me abre en una hoja de trabajo nueva el procedimiento. suerte

Answer (score 0):

Con este comando es super sencillo:

```
sp_stored_procedures[nombre_procedimiento]
```

Eso te muestra toda la estructura de tu procedimiento.

Answer (score 0):

1.- Abrir SQL server
2.- Acceder al servidor.
3.- Buscar la bd donde se creo el storeprocedure.
4.- Desplegar bases de datos.
5.- Ir a la carpeta de programación dentro de la base de datos.
6.- Ir a procedimientos almacenados y ahí estarán todos los procedimientos almacenados creados en esa base de datos.

Answer (score 0):

Sería algo asi, si sólo buscas SPs.

```
use databasename 
go 
select * from sys.procedures where name = 'storedprocedurename'
```

Answer (score 0):

Buen día, si los 2 están usando la misma consulta posiblemente sea cuestión de permisos sobre la base de datos, supongo que el DBA tiene permisos de sysadmin y a ti te puede estar faltando permisos para ver definiciones y estructuras.

Te paso una consulta que uso cuando no estoy seguro del nombre del objeto, la cual también contiene la fecha de creación y modificación para que así puedas validar que es la que estas buscando, espero que te sirva.

Saludos.

```
select distinct o.name Nombre, o.type_desc Tipo, o.create_date, o.modify_date
from sys.objects o
inner join syscomments c ON o.object_id = c.id
where c.text LIKE '%objeto%'
and o.type='P' --U Tlabla, V Vista, etc.
```

Comment: Es una pregunta de hace 7 AÑOS, además ya tiene una respuesta aceptada. Debes participar más para obtener reputación y poder comentar. Puedes hacer el [tour] para entender como funciona Stackoverflow y el apartado [answer] para tener las pautas necesarias para que tu respuesta sea marcada como aceptada.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, revisar [answer]